# Does Combining Lasers Add to Their Power?

Tags: laser

For example... If I had a 2W green laser, a 2W red laser, and a 2W blue laser, could I combine them using crystals to form a 6W white laser? Or is that now how it works? If not what would be the output in watts of such a laser?

Comment: Red and blue make purple, not white.

Comment: Does RGB not make white? I also included green.

Comment: Oh, didn't see the green.  Disregard.

Comment: The Laser Weapon System (LaWS)  combines multiple laser beams.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0DbgNju2wE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have 6 watts of total power, and the color may appear white to a human; but "white" is not a wavelength. Nothing special would happen to the light where the beams overlap, and the fact that your light sources are lasers wouldn't matter.

Comment: Now wait a second - what about destructive interference?

Comment: What about it? I'm not sure what relevance that has here.